# Computer freezes when clicking "Restart now" after Ubuntu 18.04 installation is completed

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, live-usb, restart

I wanted to start using Ubuntu, and downloaded the Ubuntu 18.04 iso. After installing it with a bootable USB stick the laptop froze. This happened when the installation was completed and I clicked the *Restart now* option.

Comment: How long have you waited when it froze? Were you able to hard reboot the machine? If so, were you able to boot to the Ubuntu you just installed?

Comment: I waited 20 mnts., then did a hard reboot, now it seems to run ubuntu, but after I logged in my desktop is empty, I can just move my mouse but nothing is available

Comment: Did you have the "Download updates while installing Ubuntu" checked? It's in the first few steps of the installation process.

Comment: Yes, I followed the tutorial, checked the boxes and continued with the installation process.

Comment: Have you tried without checking that box? Just wondering if the current state happens to have broken something. Try doing the install without update. Pretty much doing the opening day install.

Answer (score 0):

The process of installing Ubuntu has completed except for restarting the computer. Press the power key on your computer and hold it down until it force shuts down. Then boot the computer again and it should be OK.